# How do I conditionally include a catkin component only for testing?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to include unit tests in my catkin package (moveit_core), but they require a support package (moveit_resources) which I do not want to be required for normal installation of the main package (moveit_core).

This page:
http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/howto/index.html#configuring-and-running-unit-tests
says that the correct thing for unit tests is to test the CMake variable CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING.  But that option is defined in the catkin cmake files, so it won't be available until after the "find_package(catkin ...)" call.  The support package I want to conditionally include would be an argument to that same find_package(catkin ...) call, so I can't do it that way.

If I just do it the typical cmake way with an explicit "find_package(moveit_resources)" and then check the variable moveit_resources_FOUND, it comes up false when I *first* run catkin_make and true on subsequent runs of catkin_make.  This means I do have a workaround for my automated testing, but it means running catkin_make multiple times, which is slower.

So is there some way to simulate what find_package(catkin...) does for components even when they are not installed, when they are still just source packages in the current workspace?

Or maybe package.xml's test_depends tag could be put to use here?  (see http://answers.ros.org/question/115526/is-test_depend-actually-used-for-anything/ )

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,
Dave

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/115991/how-do-i-conditionally-include-a-catkin-component-only-for-testing?/) by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1351 on 2014-01-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) on 2014-01-08**:
I just filed this bug: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg/issues/83 against catkin_pkg.  As far as I can see, find_package(moveit_resources) fails the first time because moveit_resources comes later in the topological order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Any dependency required at configure / build time must be listed as a `build_depend`. `test_depend` is currently only used for additional run dependencies only need when executing the tests.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0